I am facing issue in mermaid diagram in Angularjs. the problem is able to get the mermaid diagram but not text inside it
Install the latest mermaid in the Angular using npm install mermaid, then imported into .ts file used the mermaid.initialize() and mermaid.init().
<div>

  <h2>Mermaid Graph with Subgraphs</h2>

  <textarea [(ngModel)]="mermaidInput"

placeholder="Enter Mermaid code here"></textarea>

  <button

(click)="renderMermaid()">Render Graph</button>

 

  <div class="mermaid"

id="mermaidGraph"></div>

</div>



  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.renderMermaid();

  }


[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/T5RwjyJj.png)
 

  renderMermaid(): void {

    // Initialize Mermaid and render the

graph

    mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true

});

    const mermaidGraph =

document.querySelector('#mermaidGraph') as HTMLElement;

    if (mermaidGraph) {

      mermaidGraph.innerHTML =

this.mermaidInput;

      mermaid.init(undefined,

mermaidGraph);

    }

  }

Need to get text inside the nodes when mermaid diagram rendered.
